# Optimally, if a variable is read in many threads but only written in one, should it be read non-atomically in the writing thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Specifically, should I use this template to read the variable in the writer thread for optimal performance?

```
template <typename T>
inline T load_non_atomic(const std::atomic<T> &v)
  {
    if (sizeof(std::atomic<T>) == sizeof(T))
      return(* reinterpret_cast<const T *>(&v));
    else
      return(v.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
  }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of first condition which seems UB to me.

Comment: _" should I use this template to read the variable in the writer thread for optimal performance?"_ No! One thousand times, no!

Comment: Sounds like a use case for a shared mutex.  Also don't get rid of the atomic code.  If the type is naturally atomic (like int on x86) then the code will be optimized.  You want to code there to enforce a total order.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you mean that reinterpret_cast can never be considered portable under the Standard, I think that's correct.

Comment: What problem is this trying to solve?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` has very few correct use, it is not one of them.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's a question that arguably applies to using anything in <atomic> other than sequentially consistent ordering, in practical terms.  My question is open-ended.  Answers could address whether it makes sense even hypothetically.  They could consider current architectures, or whether it has any value for future safety.

Comment: Yes, asking what is the purpose of a proposed design is "arguably" applicable to pretty much anything.  That's the idea: it's really hard to find the best route if you don't know where you're trying to go.

Comment: Why do you reinterpret_cast std::atomic<T>* to T* ? There is no guarantee that something meaningfull will happen. An atomic is not just the type it contains, even if T is small. When you access an atomic variable you have to deal with way more instructions than with a normal variable. So, this code is totally buggy and should not be used.

Comment: Because (most i saw, I did not saw much) compilers implement predefined atomics as a simple `struct` where the first member is of `volatile T`. And then you can apply the rules of standard layout type and `reinterpret_cast`. Ok I missed to mention that I am talking about predefined atomics.

Comment: @knivil why would volatile help?  I think volatile would defeat the point, to use a read or write value of v that was still register cached.  I'm not sure the standard layout rules would provide a guarantee in this case if accesses to atomic<T> were not lock-free.  The compiler might treat a read with locking and one without as distinct values.  (And if atomic<T> is lock-free, the template could not provide any performance advantage.)

Comment: I am not talking about your intention, I am talking about the above code. `volatile` is only needed to make `reinterpret_cast` on predefined atomics (with `volatile T` as first member) well formed. Thats all. There is no point in re-reading an atomic when you can cache it in another variable.

Comment: @knivil there may be a point, if the nominal read or write (resulting in the cached value) happens in an inlined function.

Comment: @WaltK: Stop discussing. You questions is answered. Note: `inline` is only a hint. The compiler is in general smarter than you. Also: `inline` applied to a template will do nothing ... nothing. And: every discussion about performance is pointless until you measure.

Comment: @knivil I meant actually inlined not nominally inlined.

Comment: @WaltK - the key to note is that `memory_order_relaxed` already gives the compiler all the freedom to implement this pretty much as efficiently as possible. Now, it could be the case that some compilers _don't_, yet - they may either apply a too-strict ordering (e.g., they have only implemented one or more of the stronger orderings and just map relaxed to it), it it may inhibit other optimizations. Based on my tests, however, both `gcc` and `clang` do a good job. `icc` does a bad job (fails in the second way)  and your "hack" currently makes a difference there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't portably or legally just cast the `std::atomic<T>` to a `T` object through a `reinterpret_cast` on a pointer like you are doing, although you will often find it works in practice.

*Other than the UB*, the primary downside is that the compiler won't necessarily reload the value each time this method is called, which is probably something you want. You may find that it simply caches the value, breaking assumptions your underlying algorithm makes (e.g., if you checking a flag in a loop, the value may never be seen in change).

In practice, `v.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` is going to generate fast code on most platforms anyway.

For example, the following code to read two `std::atomic<int>` compiles almost as well with plan `.load()` as your hack:

template

```
inline T load_cheating(const std::atomic<T> &v) {
  return (* reinterpret_cast<const T *>(&v));
}

template <typename T>
inline T load_relaxed(const std::atomic<T> &v) {
  return (v.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
}

int add_two_cheating(const std::atomic<int> &a, const std::atomic<int> &b) {
  return load_cheating(a) + load_cheating(b);
}

int add_two_relaxed(const std::atomic<int> &a, const std::atomic<int> &b) {
  return load_relaxed(a) + load_relaxed(b);
}
```

The two versions end up as:

```
add_two_cheating(std::atomic<int> const&, std::atomic<int> const&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

and

```
add_two_relaxed(std::atomic<int> const&, std::atomic<int> const&):
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        add     eax, edx
        ret
```

These have essentially identical performance<sup>1</sup>. Perhaps one day the latter will be identical, although for most practical purposes it already is.

Even on ARM, which has a weaker memory model, you pay *zero* performance cost:

```
add_two_cheating(std::atomic<int> const&, std::atomic<int> const&):
        ldr     w2, [x0]
        ldr     w0, [x1]
        add     w0, w2, w0
        ret

add_two_relaxed(std::atomic<int> const&, std::atomic<int> const&):
        ldr     w0, [x0]
        ldr     w1, [x1]
        add     w0, w1, w0
        ret
```

Identical code produced in both places (the more-or-less-RISC ARM architecture doesn't have load-op instructions so you don't see the slight difference you did on x86).

**Note** that *even on the same thread*, once you use a type-punned pointer to read or modify the variables, even the single threaded code can be broken (e.g., reads may ignore earlier writes, or, in some cases, reads can see writes that _happen in the future on the same thread).

Check out the `triple_nonatomic` examples [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Thxnyj) - they all get the single threaded behavior wrong. I didn't easily make it happen with an intervening `std::atomic.store()` type operation, probably because these aren't as optimized today (even relaxed ordering seems to imply a compiler barrier) - but they certainly may be in the future.

---

On modern x86, the same number of ops in the unfused domain, and likely the same latency, but the first one does have one less uop in the fused domain. We are taking a fraction of a cycle difference on average, if any.

Comment: You missed the point about this template being used to read the variable _only_ in the thread in which it is written.  So a change cannot be missed.

Comment: @WaltK - fair enough, although it could certainly be missed due to aliasing - the compiler doesn't need to respect writes to the variable when the subsequent reads happen through a pointer of the wrong type.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Interesting comment about type-punned pointers and reordering.

Comment: @walt - `triple_cheating` works on the compiler I tried. The `nomatomic` are the broken ones and those examples show that already today they will get the wrong answer due to such casts, and in the future they may very well do the same for the reinterpret cast even with atomics (indeed the wrong code has nothing to do with threads).

Answer (score 2):

No, what you describe is undefined behavior.

A decent optimizer will reduce an atomic read to a read if doing so is defined behavior.  You may not have a decent optimizer, or maybe your defined behavior code is asking a stricter question than you actually need.

---

If you do this, you are now responsible for auditing the generated assembly, machine code generated, the CPU and memory architecture, in every future compile of your code, across OS revisions, compiler version updates, hardware changes, etc.

So if your code is going to be compiled once, run once, then throw away, what you did is only a ridiculous amount of effort.

If it is going to have a longer lifetime, what you are doing is a nearly immesurable amount of effort to avoid random breaks in the code base at some future date.

Doing this without a lot of evidence it generates faster code (which is not in evidence), that the faster code is correct, and that the speed increase is critical to your problem, would quite simply be stupid.